# Rotated shape points after resizing inside canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, math, geometry, rotation

I am working on an application in which I have an Canvas control and user can add one or more line and/or a rectangle shapes and group them. After grouping user can resize the parent group using mouse events. Something similar to how Microsoft powerpoint allows user to add shapes and group them.

*Hierarchy of shapes inside canvas*

- Group

  - Rectangle with angle 30
  - Line with thickness 10 and angle 45

For group and child shapes Below information I am having:
Top_Left Point: Top, Left position of shape, reference point which will remain same even if shape is rotated

Point_1_Top_Left: Top, Left position of shape which will change based on angle of shape
Point_2_Top_Right: Top, Right position of shape which will change based on angle of shape
Point_3_Bottom_Right: Bottom, Right position of shape which will change based on angle of shape
Point_4_Bottom_Left: Bottom, Left position of shape which will change based on angle of shape

Width: Width of shape
Height: Height of shape
Shape_Center: Centre point of shape (Width / 2, Height / 2)

I'm using a `RotateTransform` to achieve the rotation with a 0.5, 0.5. I'm using below logic to calculate position of point which is rotated around another point by an angle.

```
        public static PointF RotatePointAroundByAngle(PointF pointToRotate, PointF centerPoint, double angleInDegrees)
        {
            double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
            double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
            double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

            return new PointF
            {
                X = (float) Math.Round((cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) - sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X),2),
                Y = (float)Math.Round((sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) + cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y),2)
            };
        }
```

**Now if the group rectangle is resized, by width Delth_Width and by heigth Delta_Height, How I can calculate the new rotated points of child shapes and their width/height?**

[Sample Grouped Shape with rotated line and a rectangle inside a grouped shape before horizontal resize and after horizontal resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WekQt.png)

Thanks,
ST

- I tried:
  Used the above function `RotatePointAroundByAngle` to update position of rotated shapes and allowed user to group them.
  Now after resizing the parent group need to know the steps and calculation logic to find all the new points of shapes and their new width/height.

Comment: I've got code can do these sort of calculations. Do you need to know where the points are though? Or would just rotating the whole group work for you?

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your inputs. I have added image in the above inside question which shows what I am trying to achieve. I need to calculate the Length of red line, angle of red line after stretching the grouped shape horizontally and Top+Left location of the red line when rotated red line is not rotated by this new angle. Can you please help me with new final values if in original image I know the length of red line, angle at which red line is rotated and original top/left position of line 
Thanks, 
ST

Answer (score 0):

There already exists an API to do all the calculations and transformations.
Just apply a matrix transformation using the current `Shape.GeometryTransform` of the shape's underlying `Geometry` (or `Geometry.Transform` when working with `Geometry` objects in general).
You can use this returned `Transform` object to get the final resulting location after applying the current `RenderTransform` to any `Point` or `Rect` (geometry bounds).

The following example shows how to transform a `Shape` (rotate and scale) and how to get the new transformed location of the `Shape`.
To support scale and rotate, the `RenderTransform` object is a `TransformGroup`, containing a `RotateTransform` and a `ScaleTransform`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Canvas x:Name="ShapeContainer"  />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CreateAndShowRectangle(new Size(50, 50), new Point(200, 200), Brushes.DarkRed);
  var shape = this.ShapeContainer.Children
    .OfType<Shape>()
    .Last();

  // Transform the shape:
  // rotate clockwise by 135 
  // and inflate shape (width and height) by factor 2 (200%)
  TransformShape(shape, 135, new Vector(2, 2));

  Point transformedShapeLocation = GetTransformedLocationOfShape(shape);
}

private void CreateAndShowRectangle(Size size, Point position, Brush fill)
{
  var rectangleShape = new Rectangle() 
  { 
    Height = size.Height, 
    Width = size.Width, 
    Fill = fill, 
  
    // Rotate and scale around the shape's center point
    RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5) 
  };

  var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();

  // Add rotation support
  transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform());

  // Add resize support
  transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());

  rectangleShape.RenderTransform = transformGroup;

  // Display the Shape
  Canvas.SetTop(rectangleShape, position.Y);
  Canvas.SetLeft(rectangleShape, position.X);
  this.ShapeContainer.Children.Add(rectangleShape);
}

private void TransformShape(Shape shape, double rotationAngle, Vector resizeFactor)
{
  TransformCollection renderTranformCollection = (shape.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children;

  RotateTransform rotateTransform = renderTranformCollection.OfType<RotateTransform>().First();
  rotateTransform.Angle = rotationAngle;
  
  ScaleTransform scaleTransform = renderTranformCollection.OfType<ScaleTransform>().First();
  scaleTransform.ScaleX = resizeFactor.X;
  scaleTransform.ScaleY = resizeFactor.Y;
}

private Point GetTransformedLocationOfShape(Shape shape)
{
  Point originalLocation = shape.RenderedGeometry.Bounds.Location;

  // Calculate the new Point based on the current RenderTransform (the TransformGroup in this case).
  // Alternatively, use the Transform.TransformBounds method.
  Point transformedLocation = shape.GeometryTransform.Transform(originalLocation);

  // Translate location relative to the containing Canvas
  return shape.TranslatePoint(transformedLocation, this.ShapeContainer);
}
```

To get the transformed point of a `Shape` that is part of a group, you apply the exact same pattern/code. This is, because the `Trasnform` is inherited to all child visuals. For example, if you group a set of `Shape` objects using a `Canvas` as group container and this grouping `Canvas` is a child of the `ShapeContainer` from the above example, then transforming this grouping `Canvas` will affect its children. In this case the above method `GetTransformedLocationOfShape` will return the correct location of each `Shape`.

---

A general transformation example to calculate the transformed point using a `Matrix`:

```
// All Point arguments must be relative to the object that the original RenderTransform was applied to
private Point GetTransformedLocationOfShape(
  Point originalLocation, 
  double rotationAngle, 
  Vector resizeFactor, 
  Point transformCenter)
{
  var transformMatrix = new Matrix();

  // The actual order of transformations is relevant!
  transformMatrix.RotateAtPrepend(rotationAngle, transformCenter.X, transformCenter.Y);
  transformMatrix.ScaleAtPrepend(resizeFactor.X, resizeFactor.Y, transformCenter.X, transformCenter.Y);

  // Calculate the new Point based on mimicking the current RenderTransform (the TransformGroup in this case)
  return transformMatrix.Transform(originalLocation);
}
```

Comment: Hello BionicCode, 
Thanks for your inputs. I have added image above inside question which shows what I am trying to achieve. I need to calculate the Length of red line, angle of red line after stretching the grouped shape horizontally and Top+Left location of the red line when rotated red line is not rotated by this new angle. Can you please help me with new final values if in original image I know the length of red line, angle at which red line is rotated and original top/left position of line
Thanks, 
ST

Comment: You get the angle with the help of simple trigonometry (the diagonal line is the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle). The location with the help of the GetTransformedLocationOfShape method from the above example.

Comment: Hello BionicCode, as you said I am able to get the new line length and angle after stretching by using trigonometry concepts. I am using properties from the viewmodel (e.g. LineViewModel) and the same are binded to respective Shape properties in UI. Due to this binding I feel I will not be able to use GetTransformedLocationOfShape method as it is. Can you please suggest how I can get the non-rotated top/left position from the viewmodel properties like length of line, angle of line, rotated top/left values ?
Thanks,
ST

Comment: While calculating the angle is completely decoupled from the actual coordinate system, calculating a point isn't. A point by definition describes a location in a specific coordinate system i.e. it is relative to a system. In your case the coordinate system is either the screen or the container that hosts the shapes. To calculate the transformed point you need the dimensions and screen location of the container host.

Comment: I don't recommend to handle this data in your view model. You should use a converter instead that converts between your data's coordinate system (for example a Cartesian system) and screen coordinates. This way your data points are decoupled from the and could be used on different clients (for example if the data is stored in a remote database  and you want to display the data correctly on different clients).

Comment: If you don't care that the points are coupled to a particular view, your MultiValueConverter can simply do the calculations for you. The converter can take the hosting Canvas as an input in order to transform the location relative to it. Basically move the GetTransformedLocationOfShape  method to a MultiValueConverter (using a MultiBinding). You can even consider to move the angle calculation to the converter too (or into a common class that the converter can use), so that all the calculations are in one place.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show a general and simple way using a Matrix.

Comment: For resizing and rotating I am using _Thumb_ classes (DragDelta event) and also user can resize the parent group shape by changing width/height property of group. When parent group is resized (parent width/height is changed), I am looping child shapes and updating their width/height by same % change. For line in the above image I am showing change in width by red dotted rectangle. Once I got the updated line width, I am updating the angle and length by trigonometry concepts. How I can use this method from _DragDelta event of Thumb class for resizing?

Comment: Maybe I will make it to post an example tomorrow that shows how to do the calculations in your item models and how to properly bind it to the view. You can then expand on this example.

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode. I will use your calculation logic and modify the logic for my application.

Comment: So you don't need an example? Simply use a Matrix to do all the calculations. You can bind a MatrixTransform to this Matrix to render the transformations. This is very straight forward. For example create a line model that has a location, length and an angle. Using the Matrix to rotate and scale it allows you to get any transformed point using Matrix.Transform.  The transform center points must be relative to the transformed object (e.g. the line). This means you don't need any UI elements to do the calculations.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need the calculations example with model data which you said earlier. Once you share that I will try using the same and modify it for my application.

Comment: Ok. I will come beech to you maybe later that day or tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry I was very busy and tired the last days. Do you still need the example?

Comment: Hello BionicCode, Ya I still need the logic using model data. I was working on some other tasks meanwhile. 
Thanks in advance,
ST